# How do I change the name of an app in CMD + TAB switcher?

Tags: mac, application-switcher

On my Mac, I want to run two instances of an app, each in a different `Space`. However, when I use <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> I see all apps (not limited to the current `Space`) and both app instances have the same icon and same app name.

Since the order of the icons is not what I expect, I seem to switch to the wrong app instance more often than not.

How do I either:

1. Change the app name?
2. Change the app icon?
3. Limit the apps to only those in the current Space?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Create a soft link of the app with a different name.

```
ln -s /Applications/MyApp.app /Applications/OtherName.app
```

Step 2. Run the app in the link.

```
/Applications/OtherName.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp
```

You may want to create a script in your path to facilitate starting the app.

You may also need to supply arguments to the app so that two instances run without conflicting each other. In my particular example, the application was DBeaver, eg.

```
/Applications/OtherName.app/Contents/MacOS/dbeaver -data ~/Library/DBeaverData/someworkspace &>/dev/null &
```